# How to use list.append() in pandas loops?

Tags: python, pandas

[image: DataFrame]

I have 2 questions:

1. I have a dataset that contains some duplicate IDs, but some of them have different actions so they can't be removed. I want for each ID to do some math and store the final value to work with later. I already have duplicate indices, but in this code, it doesn't work properly and gives NaN.
2. How can I write nested loop using pandas? Cause it takes too much time to run. I've already used iterrows(), but didn't work.

   ```
      l_list = []
    for i in range(len(idx)):
        for j in range(len(idx[i])):
            if df.at[j,'action'] == 0:
                a = df.rank[idx[i]]*50
                b = df.study_list[idx[i]].str.strip('[]').str.split(',').str.len()
                l_list.append(a + b)
   ```

Comment: Please post an example from your input dataframe and the expected output.

Comment: @navneethc I made an example and added an image. For example for ID = aaa, if its action is 0, I want its rank * 50 + the number of items in the study_list, which is 2. Then for other IDs = aaa with action = 0, doing the same and finaly have a value for this ID to work with later. I want to do this for all the IDs and have their assigned value.

Comment: In the future, please use the recommendations given in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples to post questions about Pandas.

Comment: @navneethc thanks a lot. I'm sorry about that, I'm new to this community and didn't know the rules exactly. Thank you so much for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my understanding of what you've provided, see if this works:

```
In [15]: df
Out[15]:
    ID  rank  action    study_list
0  aaa    24       0        [a, b]
1  bbb     6       1     [1, 2, 3]
2  aaa    14       0  [1, 2, 3, 4]

In [16]: def do_thing(row):
    ...:     if row['ID'] == 'aaa' and row['action'] == 0:
    ...:         return row['rank'] * 50 + len(row['study_list'])
    ...:     else:
    ...:         return 100 * row['rank']
    ...:

In [17]: df['new_value'] = df.apply(do_thing, axis=1)

In [18]: df
Out[18]:
    ID  rank  action    study_list  new_value
0  aaa    24       0        [a, b]       1202
1  bbb     6       1     [1, 2, 3]        600
2  aaa    14       0  [1, 2, 3, 4]        704
```

NOTE:
I have made many simplifications as your post doesn't enable a reproducible case. Read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) to see how to best ask questions about Pandas.
I also can't guarantee speed as you have not provided the details regarding the size of the dataset.

Answer (score 0):

i dont know what does the variable idx or anything. i think your code is wrong,
you have to try this code

```
l_list = []
for i in range(len(idx)):
 for j in range(len(idx[i])):
     if df.at[j,'action'] == 0:
         a = df.rank[idx[i]]*50
         b = df.study_list[idx[i]].str.strip('[]').str.split(',').str.len()
         l_list.append(a + b)
```